# Xamarin Android httpClient.getAsync causes Exception

Tags: c#, .net, rest, xamarin.android, rest-client

When i call

```
public static async Task<User> GetUserAsync(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Resource.RestBaseURI);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("APIKey", Resource.APIKey);

                var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync($"api/Users/{name}");
                if (!responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    throw new HttpResponseException(responseMessage.StatusCode);
                var userDb = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<UserDb>().Result;

                if (userDb == null)
                    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

                var user = DbClientConverter.UserDbToUser(userDb);

                user.RefuelEntityList = await RefuelEntityCommunicator.GetRefuelEntitiesAsync(user);

                return user;
            }
        }
        catch (HttpResponseException httpResponseException)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(httpResponseException.Response.StatusCode);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException(httpRequestException.Message, httpRequestException);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new Exception(exception.Message, exception);
        }
    }
```

on Xamarin Android

the await client.GetAsync in line 12 causes a exception:

> "The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.FormattingUtilities' threw an exception"

the same code used in a WPF Application is no problem.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried? var userDb = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<UserDb>();

Comment: Do not mix async and blocking `.Result` calls as that can lead to deadlocks. Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: It seems that some dependencies are broken. Have you tried to reinstall NuGet package?

From the package manager, run Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -reinstall.

Solution 2: use NuGet to install the Web API 2.1 WebHost.

Solution 3: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -Version 5.x.x

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85204/problem-is-could-not-load-type-system-net-http-formattingutilities

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("APIKey", Resource.APIKey);
```

Use

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("APIKey", Resource.APIKey);
```

This is becuase "APIKey" here is a non-standard custom header

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a problem with `ReadAsAsync` extension method. 
See [here](https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2017/10/httpcontent-readasasync-with-net-core-2/) for a custom solution.